# Dynamic class name from hash value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I have a tab set with unique id for each. And a function with unique className from the upload button in each tab. So I want to grab the hash value to build a new className dynamically. To use with the function I built.

Example:

```
URL : www.myweb.com/upload.php#tab1
```

**jS**

```
var hash=location.hash;//grab hash = tab1
$('.upload_'.hash).uploadPic({//expect className= '.upload_tab1'
.
.
.
});
```

**html**

```
<button id="upload_tab1">Browse</button>
```

I've tried but it is not working for some reasons. No error, nothing. Please help.

Comment: use `+` to concat string in js not a `.`

Comment: still not working, @guradio

Comment: to add class use something like `$('.upload_').addClass(hash)`

Comment: @guradio, I know now. Because `location.hash` gives me `#tab1`. So the className is `upload_#tab1` instead of `upload_tab1`.

So I change to `window.location.hash.substr(1)` which giving me only value only.

Comment: yes because  of ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. `+ to Concat` in javascript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you need to use `+` instead of `.` to concatenate strings in JavaScript.

However, that will still not solve your issue, because the value returned by `window.location.hash`, includes the hash (`#`) sign that precedes the fragment:

```
const hash = window.location.hash; // value is "#tab1"
```

So you need to strip off the hash sign:

```
const hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); // value is "tab1"
```

To prevent errors in cases where the fragment is not specified, you might want to check for the presence of the hash sign first:

```
let hash = window.location.hash;
hash = hash.startsWith('#') ? hash.substring(1) : hash;
```

Comment: This is working, just change the way grabbing the hash value and cut `#` off!

Comment: I also have data attribute in each button. But it's not taken by the script: `<button class="upload_tab1" data-cate="head" data-size="S">Browse</button>`. I use ajax to grab data : `formData: {"cate":$(this).attr("data-cate"),"size":$(this).attr("data-size")},` but It's not passing trough the form. Any idea?

Comment: Probably better to ask a new question and add the relevant code. This might help: https://api.jquery.com/data/